# Getting FFmpeg to Recursive scan and output to Static folder

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch, script, video-conversion

How Can i change my FFmpeg script .batch file to output the Video.Mkv to output to a  Folder Called "FIXED" in the same directory of the script.

```
Mk Fixed
for /R %%f IN (*.mkv) do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -map 0:m:language=English? -c copy "%%~nf.MKV"
```

Currently it scans the main folder and Subfolder for any Mkv's and keeps only the English Audio Track but it outputs all the Mkv's in the same folder (as the script) instead of the static folder "Fixed"

I have another Script that does what i need but couldn't get it to work with Recursive scanning subfolders for batch scanning this outputs to the correct folder.

```
Mk Fixed
for %%a in ("*mkv*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -map 0:0 -c:v copy -map 0:3 -c:a copy "Fixed\%%~na".mkv
```

if i try adding "fixed\%%~nf.Mkv" to my my first script I get

```
[matroska,webm @ 0000018fb8518840] File ended prematurely
```

if i could even have it keep the directory (from the source) to the (Destination) ) structure in the output folder that would be great to.

--reply i have modified my script to

```
mkdir Fixed
for /R %%f IN (*.mkv) do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -map 0:m:language=English? -c copy "Fixed\%%~nf.mkv"
```

this works but i still can't get the output to contain the sub folders structure.

I would like FFMpeg to go though (scanning sub directorys) and convert the video files.
well maintaining the folder strucker

More information that i mistakenly should have included.
O.S Windows 10 Pro
Directory structure
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Convert (with the Files in need to convert Inside)
Folder where FFFMPEG and Script.Bat File is Plus sub folders of files needing convert.

```
Example C:\Users\User\Desktop\Convert\Tv Show\Show 1\Season 1\Show.mkv
Goal C:\Users\User\Desktop\Convert\Fixed\Tv Show\Show 1\Season 1\Show.mkv
```

Comment: Maybe `".\Fixed\%%~nf.mkv"`?

Comment: i have tried the first suggestions with no luck still doesn't work. it puts everything in the same folder without the structure i am trying to keep. the os is windows 10 pro running as a batch file in the root of the directory with the sub directories there. with SOMEBADHAT that stript ends up making a bunch of files named with all those expressions that are in the stript

Comment: `for /R %%f IN (*.mkv) do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -map 0:m:language=English? -c copy "%USERPROFILE%\DESKTOP\CONVERT\Fixed\TV SHOW\SHOW 1\SEASON 1\%%~nf.mkv"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Ended up using a program to get the results I need "FFmpeg Batch AV Converter" it allows me to run my script and add an option of keeping the source folder struct in the output directory. there is an option in the bottom right of the program for that.
Thanks for all the help, I didnt didnt get the outcome I was expecting with just the bat file. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjV6B.png)